# Loading Silverlight controls by reading from XAML File in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have to read a XAML file in a Silverlight application and load controls from the XAML file directly into the Application. How can I do this?

Comment: A lot of people have assisted you with your silverlight questions, if their answer is correct (like the below one) then at least do them the favour of marking their amswers as the answer. To not do so is kind of rude, and doesn't help anyone else who searches and finds your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, check out this thread:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/1611.aspx

Also, checkout the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class